# Infinite amount of numbers such that $x_n > 1/n$. Then $\sum_n x_n$ doesn't converge

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

(**Edit:** Here $\mathbb{R}_0$ means $\mathbb{R} \setminus \left\{0 \right\}$. Same for $\mathbb{N}_0$.)

I need to prove the following:

**Problem:** Let $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}_0}$ be a decreasing sequence in $\mathbb{R}_0$. Suppose there exist an infinite amount of numbers $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$ such that $x_n > \frac{1}{n}$. Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n$ doesn't converge.

**Attempt:** Let $$s_n = \sum_{k = 1}^n = x_k$$ be the $n$th partial sum. Then we have $s_n - s_{n-1} = x_n$. There exist an infinite amount of $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$ such that $x_n > 1/n$. Because $\lim_{n \to \infty} 1/n = 0$, it follows by taking the limit that $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} s_n - \lim_{n \to \infty} s_{n-1} = \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n \geq 0. $$ Now I want to conclude from this somehow that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n \neq 0$, and hence the series is not convergent (because the terms don't go to zero). Would this be correct reasoning?

Comment: The sequence $x_n = 2/n$ satisfies the hypotheses, but $\lim x_n = 0$. So your strategy won't work.

Comment: Note that the fact that the sequence is decreasing is absolutely crucial.

Comment: What about Weierstrass M-test?

Comment: @CaptainLama, How can I use that assumption in my proof? Can I conclude that $s_n < s_{n-1}$?

Comment: What is $\mathbb{R}_0$?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}_0 = \mathbb{R} \setminus \left\{0 \right\}$.

Comment: Oops! I could have sworn $\;\Bbb R_0\;$ is the set (linear space or whatever) of real sequences converging to zero...

Comment: The $\mathbb{R}_0$ thing is a red herring. If $x_n $ is non increasing and $x_n > { 1\over n} $ infinitely often then it follows that $x_n >0 $ always.

Comment: Take an increasing sequence of indices $n_k$ with $x_{n_k}>1/(n_k)$. Then $\sum_{n=n_{k-1}+1}^{n_k} x_n>(n_k-n_{k-1})/n_k$. Now you can sum this inequality over $k$. On the left side you will get $\sum_{n=n_1}^\infty x_n$; $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ can only be bigger than this. (We have done a rearrangement, but it is a sum of positive terms so this does not matter.) What happens on the right side?

Comment: @Ian What *does* happen on the right side? I couldn't obtain a useful bound. Of course, $(n_k - n_{k-1})/n_k = 1 - n_{k-1}/n_k$, but $n_{k-1}/n_k$ can be arbitrarily near $1$. How can we constrain how quickly it approaches $1$? The solution by copper.hat shows that this is a bit subtle - I'm curious whether you found something more straightforward.

Comment: The worst case in terms of $n_{k-1}/n_k$ being close to $1$ would be $n_k=c+k$ for some $c$. In this case you just have a lower bound of the harmonic series itself, minus the first finitely many terms. With the opposite extreme, where $n_{k-1}/n_k$ is very small, you are essentially summing $1$. What I'm not so sure how to handle is the intermediate regime, where $n_{k-1}/n_k$ converges to $1$ but relatively slowly. It looks like copper.hat figured this out.

Answer (score 4):

If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ converges, then we must have $\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty x_n=0.$ Choose $N$ so that $\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty x_n\lt\frac12.$ Choose $k\gt2N$ with $x_k\ge\frac1k.$ Then
$$\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty x_n\ge\sum_{n=N+1}^k x_n\ge\sum_{n=N+1}^k\frac1k=\frac{k-N}k\gt\frac{k-\frac12k}k=\frac12$$
contradicting the way $N$ was chosen.

A slightly more general formulation: if $\{x_n\}$ is a decreasing sequence of positive numbers, and if $\limsup_{n\to\infty}nx_n\gt0,$ then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ diverges.

Answer (score 2):

Let $n_k$ be the subsequence for which the condition holds.

Note that $\sum_n x_n > \sum_k (1 - {n_k \over n_{k+1}})$.

Let $r = \liminf_k {n_k \over n_{k+1}}$. Note that $r \le 1$.

If $r<1$, then for some $r < \rho <1$ and $k$ sufficiently large
we have $(1 - {n_k \over n_{k+1}}) > 1-\rho$ infinitely often, hence
the series is divergent.

Hence $r=1$, and for some $k_0$ sufficiently large we have ${n_k \over n_{k+1}} > {1 \over 2}$ for $k \ge k_0$.

We now mimic the proof that $\sum_n { 1\over n}$ is divergent.

In particular, this shows that $n_{k_0+i} < 2^i n_{k_0}$, and, in particular,
the range of indices
$2^{m}n_{k_0},...,2^{m+1}n_{k_0}-1$ must contain at least one index for which
$x_n > {1 \over n}$ and so
$\sum_{i=2^{m}n_{k_0}}^{2^{m+1}n_{k_0}-1} x_n > \sum_{i=2^{m}n_{k_0}}^{2^{m+1}n_{k_0}-1} {1 \over 2^{m+1}n_{k_0}} = {1 \over 2}$, and summing over a suitable range of $m$ shows that the series is
divergent.